# Weirdness with tables and paddings

Tags: html, css, html-table, padding

I think this example speaks for itself: http://jsfiddle.net/FLRka/1/

The expected result for me is that the blue box should be docked with the top of the page, why is it getting a padding as well?
It's not getting 100px padding though, it's less than that.

Here is the HTML from the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>

    <body style="margin:0px">
        <table style="width:100%; height:100%; border-spacing:0px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:50%">
                    <div style="height:100px; background-color:red; padding-top:100px;"></div>
                </td>
                <td style="width:50%">
                    <div style="height:100px; background-color:blue;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `vertical-align` for table cells is `middle`.

If you add this, you'll get your expected result:

```
td {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FLRka/3/

Answer (score 3):

This is because of the height of the table row becomes 200px; (100 padding + 100 px div) and td by default have middle vertical alignment So you're getting 50px above and below the 100 pixel div.

here is the fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/FLRka/2/

Answer (score -1):

Because the stuff in the table cell vertical aligns in the middle (/ center).